# VBA Help VLookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am sort of a novice with VBA. running into an issue. I am trying to say If this value in this table is 2 then execute these formulas if not stop and give a message "Not Done."

```
If "=VLOOKUP(D8,'Sheet'!B:J,9,false)" = 2 Then

Range("I8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D8,'Sheet'!B:J,2,false)"
Range("J8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D8,'Sheet'!B:J,3,false)"
Range("K8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=G8-N8"

Else

Range("J8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "Not Done"
Range("K8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "Not Done"


Range("I8:K8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I8:K" & Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, it might be better to just bake the "is 2 or not" logic into the formula directly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that isn't simply repeating the information already available in the tags. Your title should describe a problem or question in a way that will have meaning for future users of the site who are searching for a solution to a similar problem. Your current title is not helpful for that purpose. Repeating the tags is meaningless. Thanks.

Comment: `If "=VLOOKUP(D8,'Sheet'!B:J,9,false)" = 2 Then` is problematic because `"=VLOOKUP(D8,'Sheet'!B:J,9,false)"` is just text (`String`), not a formula that is evaluated. It's no different than saying `If "abracadabra" = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA:

```
If Application.Vlookup(ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value, _
              Sheets("Sheet").Range("B:J"), 9, False) = 2 Then
```